# If / Else in DIV statement?

Tags: javascript, html

First, I am not a programmer anymore... It's been years since doing it and even then it was only VBA and old school HTML.

What I would like to do is to show an image on my site in place of another depending on it's "state". For example, the site is http://w2zxl.hevener.com/ , towards the bottom of the page is a script that loads a HAM radio logbook as well as my current status in nearly real time. If I am on the Air, it will show a small image that says ***"On Air"*** and then show what *frequency* I am on and the *Mode* I am working in. When I am off the air however, that little image just disappears and shows nothing.

What I would like to do is to create a small image to replace the *"nothing"*. In other words, if I am Off Air, I would like to show an *"Off Air"* image instead of nothing at all.

Is there an If/Then/Else statement that can do this given the code I am providing below?

#### Code below:

```
<!-- HRDLOG.net script start --><center>
<div id="hrdlog-oa"> </div>
<div id="hrdlog">www.hrdlog.net</div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.hrdlog.net/hrdlog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">// <![CDATA[
var ohrdlog = new HrdLog('W2ZXL');
setInterval('ohrdlog.LoadOnAir()', 5000);
ohrdlog.LoadLastQso(10);
// ]]></script>
<img src="http://www.hrdlog.net/callplate.aspx?user=W2ZXL" alt="W2ZXL CallPlate" /></center><!-- HRDLOG.net script stop -->
```

Comment: Sorry I have little experience in this direct area, but what you will do is load the status in your script, then set a named resource to either the on image or off image based on the status returned by your function (still inside the script). Then your div will just load the named resource, which will be the proper image. Apologies for lack of exact code/syntax

Comment: so basically, check the return of `ohrdlog.LoadOnAir()` and set your `img src` to the variable set by that logic, if that helps clear things up a bit

Comment: You might want to take a look at a templating engine, like https://github.com/janl/mustache.js (inverted sections should do the job)

Comment: In 2013 you don't need a CDATA block around your script unless you're forced to create XHTML.

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the file http://www.hrdlog.net/hrdlog.js?

Comment: Thanks guys, will work with these and see what I can get...and no, I don't have access to hrdlog.js unfortunately. The code in the answer below does not work for some reason...simply shows "www.hrdlog.net" as text and nothing else when off air. Thanks though! It is interesting that you found that though...good to see it was being looked at by others as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can not do that with pure HTML and you had 2 way for solving this

1. If you like markup languages you can use xsl that have if else tag for you
2. Using Javascript and check if you be on air show on air image and if you not be shows off air

for you the better way is change some javascript code in your site..

you should overwrite ohrdlog.LoadOnAir then you have two way again:

1. change http://www.hrdlog.net/hrdlog.js source code and rewrite LoadOnAir function
2. overwrite LoadOnAir function with inserting script tag after load http://www.hrdlog.net/hrdlog.js

i choose number 2 for you because i think you can`t change script that you load it from another domain address... now you should insert this code after this part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.hrdlog.net/hrdlog.js"></script>
```

and you can found link of offair image in HrdLog.prototype.ShowOffAir function that now, i point it to http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_Dr3YNV7OXvw/TGNNf561yQI/AAAAAAAABIk/-E2MB4jLP_o/s400/Off-Air.jpg:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
HrdLog.prototype.ShowOffAir = function() {
    return '[<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEr1B.jpg" height="33" width="65" />][2]';
}
HrdLog.prototype.LoadOnAir = function() {
    var t = this;
    var async = new Async();
    async.complete = function(status, statusText, responseText, responseXML, obj) {
        if (status == 200) {
            txt = '';

            var xmldoc = responseXML;
            var onairdoc = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('OnAir');
            if (onairdoc.length == 1) {
                onair = onairdoc.item(0);
                if (onair.getElementsByTagName('oa_QRZ').length > 0) {
                    txt += '<img src="http://www.hrdlog.net/images/onair.gif" height="33" width="65" /><br/>';
                    txt += '<font size="+1">' + onair.getElementsByTagName('oa_QRZ')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ' is on air</font><br/>';
                    txt += '<b>';
                    txt += FormatNumber(onair.getElementsByTagName('oa_Frequency')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + '&nbsp;';
                    try {
                        txt += onair.getElementsByTagName('oa_Mode')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</b><br/>';
                        txt += onair.getElementsByTagName('oa_Radio')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '<br/><br/>';
                    } catch (e) { }
                    //txt += onair.getElementsByTagName('oa_Status')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '<br/>';
                }else{
                    txt += t.ShowOffAir();
                }
            }else{
                txt += t.ShowOffAir();
            }

            element = document.getElementById('hrdlog-oa');
            if (element != null) {
                element.innerHTML = txt;
            }

        } else {
            alert('Error\n' + statusText);
        }
    }

    if ((new Date().getTime() - this._lastLoadOnAir.getTime()) > 14500) {
        this._lastLoadOnAir = new Date();
        async.req(this._host + 'hrdlog.aspx?onair=' + this._qrz, this);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: does not work for some reason...simply shows "www.hrdlog.net" as text and nothing else when off air. Thanks though! It is interesting that you found that though...good to see it was being looked at by others as well.

Comment: @W2ZXL sorry i test it again i forgot that write var t = this; for async method that used in the code.. i edited it please check it again i promiss its work fine.. ;D

Comment: Sorry for the delay...long day :) . Anyway, I tried it again and still no go...in fact it seems to have gotten rid of the logbook portion altogether as well....sure appreciate you trying though :D. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score -1):

Consider swapping CSS classes to change the `background-image` instead. This will simplify the javascript and html markup. When you're on air change the class to `onair` and toggle as needed to `offair`.

**CSS**

```
.onair {
    background-image: url("onair.jpg");
}
.offair {
    background-image: url("offair.jpg");
}
```

**Html**

```
<div id="hrdlog-oa" class="offair"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var statusDiv = document.getElementById("hrdlog-oa");

if (statusDiv.className == "offair") {
    statusDiv.className = "onair";
}
else {
    statusDiv.className = "offair";
}
```

Working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jasenhk/qMAZU/ using `background-color` instead.

Comment: That is an interesting idea...will take a look. Thanks!